# SCORM package (e-learning course) localisation

Tags: localization, text-extraction, scorm

I have to prepare e-learning course for translation in a CAT tool, but I don't have experience with this type of content.
The client sent me a SCORM package, containing mainly js, xml and HTML files. 
I can work with them, but I am not sure if the course will work properly after translation and I don't know how to test it?

Can I use the SCORM package or I have to ask for text extraction from the authoring tool in which the course was created?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to test a SCORM package is to create a free account on SCORM Cloud, https://cloud.scorm.com. Once you have an account you'll be able to upload the zip file, launch the content and see how it plays and what it records, etc. The tool also allows re-uploading to see the different version, etc. If you have trouble or questions email support@scorm.com for assistance. I didn't understand the second question, it probably depends on which authoring tool and how extensive the edits are.

(Full disclosure I work for Rustici Software who owns SCORM Cloud.)

Comment: Thank you Brian!

I already have tried with SCORM Cloud, but the package is bigger than 100MB and I can't import it with the trial version. Do you support text extraction (and back import) in XML or XLIFF format for SCORM packages??

Comment: Can try contacting support@scorm.com about the size limit thing, not sure how that is handled for free accounts. I've not heard of such things, so not that I'm aware of, but again could see if our support team has more info about them.

Comment: If you want to get creative you can bypass upload limits by getting your content on a CDN/Server and only importing a index.html and point to the files just like you would if you were using maxcdn, cdnjs etc ... just may mean a little path re-authoring.